# How to grouping value by key in object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have problem when I wanna grouping my object value data by `key` in javascript. I have data object like this.

my data :

```
const obj = [
    {total_present: "35", total_overtime: "12"},
    {total_present: "25", total_overtime: "5"},
    {total_present: "15", total_overtime: "15"},
    {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "13"},
    {total_present: "31", total_overtime: "22"},
    {total_present: "17", total_overtime: "15"},
    {total_present: "19", total_overtime: "19"},
    {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "14"},
    {total_present: "24", total_overtime: "11"},
    {total_present: "21", total_overtime: "10"}
];
```

and I wanna mannipulate it to this :

```
{
   total_overtime: ["12", "5", "15", "13", "22", "15", "19", "14", "11", "10"]
   total_present:  ["35", "25", "15", "23", "31", "17", "19", "23", "24", "21"]
}
```

How it possible I make my data to like that?

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Comment: The second isn't a valid object. Please fix the desired output. I assume you want this: `const data = { total_present: obj.map(o => o.total_present), total_overtime: obj.map(o => o.total_overtime) }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to achieve this:

```
const objGrouped = {
  total_present: ["35", "25", "15", "23", "31", "17", "19", "23", "24", "21"],
  total_overtime: ["12", "5", "15", "13", "22", "15", "19", "14", "11", "10"]
}
```

You can do this:

```
const objGrouped = {
  total_present: obj.map(item => item.total_present),
  total_overtime: obj.map(item => item.total_overtime),
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 4):

```js
const obj = [
    {total_present: "35", total_overtime: "12"},
    {total_present: "25", total_overtime: "5"},
    {total_present: "15", total_overtime: "15"},
    {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "13"},
    {total_present: "31", total_overtime: "22"},
    {total_present: "17", total_overtime: "15"},
    {total_present: "19", total_overtime: "19"},
    {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "14"},
    {total_present: "24", total_overtime: "11"},
    {total_present: "21", total_overtime: "10"}
];

console.log(
[
  {total_present: obj.map(item => item.total_present)},
  {total_overtime: obj.map(item => item.total_overtime)}
]
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce it.

```js
const obj = [
    {total_present: "35", total_overtime: "12"},
    {total_present: "25", total_overtime: "5"},
    {total_present: "15", total_overtime: "15"},
    {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "13"},
    {total_present: "31", total_overtime: "22"},
    {total_present: "17", total_overtime: "15"},
    {total_present: "19", total_overtime: "19"},
    {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "14"},
    {total_present: "24", total_overtime: "11"},
    {total_present: "21", total_overtime: "10"}
];

let result = obj.reduce((a,{total_present, total_overtime}) => {
   a.total_present.push(total_present);
   a.total_overtime.push(total_overtime);
   return a;
},{total_present: [], total_overtime: []})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
const list = [
    {total_present: "35", total_overtime: "12"},
    {total_present: "25", total_overtime: "5"},
    {total_present: "15", total_overtime: "15"},
    {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "13"},
    {total_present: "31", total_overtime: "22"},
    {total_present: "17", total_overtime: "15"},
    {total_present: "19", total_overtime: "19"},
    {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "14"},
    {total_present: "24", total_overtime: "11"},
    {total_present: "21", total_overtime: "10"}
];

const result = Object.entries(list[0]).map(([key]) => {
  return {[key]: list.map(obj => obj[key])};
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array and take the entries for the result set.

```js
const 
    array = [{ total_present: "35", total_overtime: "12" }, { total_present: "25", total_overtime: "5" }, { total_present: "15", total_overtime: "15" }, { total_present: "23", total_overtime: "13" }, { total_present: "31", total_overtime: "22" }, { total_present: "17", total_overtime: "15" }, { total_present: "19", total_overtime: "19" }, { total_present: "23", total_overtime: "14" }, { total_present: "24", total_overtime: "11" }, { total_present: "21", total_overtime: "10" }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (r[k] = r[k] || []).push(v));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = [] , b = [];
for(let i in obj){
 a.push(obj[i].total_present);
 b.push(obj[i].total_overtime);
}
var newArray = { total_present: a,total_overtime:b};
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const obje = [
  {total_present: "35", total_overtime: "12"},
  {total_present: "25", total_overtime: "5"},
  {total_present: "15", total_overtime: "15"},
  {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "13"},
  {total_present: "31", total_overtime: "22"},
  {total_present: "17", total_overtime: "15"},
  {total_present: "19", total_overtime: "19"},
  {total_present: "23", total_overtime: "14"},
  {total_present: "24", total_overtime: "11"},
  {total_present: "21", total_overtime: "10"}
];

resx=obje.reduce((res,cur)=>{
    res["total_present"]= res["total_present"] || []
    res["total_present"].push(cur.total_present)
    res["total_overtime"]=res["total_overtime"] || []
    res["total_overtime"].push(cur.total_overtime)

    return res
},{})
console.log(resx)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
let mapper={}
for(let item of obj){
   for(let key in item){
      if(mapper[key]){
         mapper[key].push(item[key])
      }else{
         mapper[key]=[item[key]]
      }
   }
}
```